# Retornar último index do Array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte código que vai me trazer uma lista indeterminada;  por exemplo 5 itens. Eu gostaria de retornar apenas o último item da lista.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){

      if(Date.parse(data.list[i].date) >= dateA){
          console.log(data.list[i].date);

      }
```

Comment: Fernando, nos comentários vc diz que quer pegar uma data maior do que "hoje", mas a pergunta diz que quer pegar o último item. Está contraditório isso. Explique bem na pergunta o que realmente você deseja.

Answer (score 4):

Dado que o índice do *array* inicia em 0, basta você acessar a posição referente ao tamanho do *array* menos um:

```js
const valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log("O último valor é:", valores[valores.length - 1]);
```

Desta forma você não depende de bibliotecas de terceiros e não modifica o *array* original, acessando, sempre, o último valor com um tempo `O(1)`, isto é, constante independente do tamanho do *array*.

Comment: o ultimo do data.list[i], olhe no meu codigo questa que vai listar apenas as datas maiores que a data de hoje por exemplo dia 28/03 e 30/03 e eu quero pegar o 30/03 que esta em ultimo na lsita

Comment: @FernandoAntunes então, basta analisar a lógica e adaptá-la para a sua necessidade. Se precisa o último elemento de um *array*, é assim que faz, independente de qual seja o *array*.

Answer (score 1):

Vendo que a sua *lista* é uma array, você não precisa nem fazer laço `for` para retornar o último item, basta usar o método [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) e pegar o primeiro índice `[0]`:

```js
var data = {
   list: [
      {
         date: "2018/01/10"
      },
      {
         date: "2018/01/09"
      },
      {
         date: "2018/05/01"
      }
   ]
}

console.log(data.list.reverse()[0].date); // retorna o último valor: 2018/05/01
```

Pode usar `.pop()` também:

```js
var data = {
   list: [
      {
         date: "2018/01/10"
      },
      {
         date: "2018/01/09"
      },
      {
         date: "2018/05/01"
      }
   ]
}

console.log(data.list.pop().date); // retorna o último valor: 2018/05/01
```

> **Nota:** o problema é que o `.pop()` irá também remover o último item da array. Então não use ele caso queira manter a integridade da array.

Comment: eu preciso retornar apenas a ultima index do que esta dentro do data.list[i].date não do data.list

Comment: O último de cada índice?

Comment: o ultimo do data.list[i], olhe no meu codigo questa que vai listar apenas as datas maiores que a data de hoje por exemplo dia 28/03 e 30/03 e eu quero pegar o 30/03 que esta em ultimo na lsita

Comment: Ficou confuso porque no `for` vc colocou `data.list.length`, ou seja, está procurando um item dentro de `data.list`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o _.last, conforme explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331284/7259765):

```
data = [1,2,3]
last = _.last(data)
alert(last)
```

Comment: Uma curiosidade: o que seria o `_`?

Comment: @dvd basicamente é o equivalente ao `$` do jQuery da biblioteca *loadash*. Um objeto que serve de namespace para as funções da biblioteca.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss humm... tentei rodar aqui e deu `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ah tah.. olhei o link indicado... é uma biblioteca...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o metodo [at(index)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), ele retorna o elemento contido no index, se adicionar -1, retorna o ultimo, -2 o penúltimo ...

```js
data = {
 list:[1,2,3, 4]
}


console.log(data.list.at(-1))
```